# ag-grid: ngIf's within cell components are not triggered on data change in rowData

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We are using `custom cell rendering from ag-grid`.
The component rendered is based on a object value set in row data

Below screenshot shows the usage of the component. However when any property value changes in the object I don’t see change detection being called, hence `ngIf`'s within cell component are not triggered

[image]

Can anyone please suggest how we can get around this problem ?

Comment: If you remove the *ngIf, does everything else work properly?  I had a problem with a seemingly non-working ngIf where a component that was in tab 2 of a tab control had a problem but the tab control displayed fine (while showing tab 1).  For some reason this prevented the ngIf functioning, but I didn't realise until I tried to open the second tab that it was actually the component's fault.

Comment: Thanks @mcalex, its actually issue with another library which apparently was removing the whole markup used within cell renderer component.